# SparkSQL errors when using SQL DATE function

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In Spark I am trying to execute SQL queries on a temporary table derived from a data frame that I manually built by reading a csv file and converting the columns into the right data type.

Specifically, the table I'm talking about is the LINEITEM table from [TPC-H specification][1]. Unlike stated in the specification I am using TIMESTAMP rather than DATE because I've read that Spark does not support the DATE type.

In my single scala source file, after creating the data frame and registering a temporary table called "lineitem", I am trying to execute the following query:

```
val res = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM lineitem l WHERE date(l.shipdate) <= date('1998-12-01 00:00:00');")
```

When I submit the packaged jar using spark-submit, I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.75] failure: ``union'' expected but but `;' found

When I omit the semicolon and do the same thing, I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: date

Spark version is 1.4.0.

Does anyone have an idea what's the problem with these queries?

[1] http://www.tpc.org/TPC_Documents_Current_Versions/pdf/tpch2.17.1.pdf

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2562

Answer (score 7):

1. SQL queries passed to `SQLContext.sql` shouldn't be delimited using semicolon - this the source of your first problem
2. `DATE` UDF expects date in the YYYY-­MM-­DD form and `DATE('1998-12-01 00:00:00')` evaluates to `null`. As long as `timestamp` can be casted to `DATE` correct query string looks like this:

   ```
   "SELECT * FROM lineitem l WHERE date(l.shipdate) <= date('1998-12-01')"
   ```
3. `DATE` is a Hive UDF. It means you have to use `HiveContext` not a standard `SQLContext` - this is the source of your second problem.

   ```
   import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext

   val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc) // where sc is a SparkContext
   ```
4. In Spark >= 1.5 it is also possible to use `to_date` function:

   ```
   import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lit, to_date}

   df.where(to_date($"shipdate") <= to_date(lit("1998-12-01")))
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Please try hive function `CAST (expression AS toDatatype)`
It changes an `expression` from one datatype to other 
e.g. `CAST ('2016-06-17 00.00.000' AS DATE)` will convert String to Date 
 In your case 
`val res = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM lineitem l WHERE CAST(l.shipdate as DATE) <= CAST('1998-12-01 00:00:00' AS DATE);")`

Supported datatype conversions are as listed in [Hive Casting Dates](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-CastingDates)

Comment: A little bit of explanation would not hurt, see [Explaining entirely code-based answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers)

Comment: @J.J.Hakala Thanks for information. I am still learning about how to work on stackoverflow. Will keep in mind about this.